# Can an object in Realm return its containing object in a query?

Tags: android, realm

eg.

```
class Question extends RealmObject
{ 
    Answer answer;
}
```

_

```
class Answer extends RealmObject
{
    String ding;
}
```

In a query can an Answer object link to the Question that holds it? Or do I have to create a new field in Answer that links to the Question that contains it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called backlinks, but isn't implemented yet. You can follow progress here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607, but currently you will have to create and maintain a bidirectional link to be able to query the container object.